# Ambari cluster URI and URI for installed services

Tags: cluster-computing, ambari

I have setup a cluster using Ambari that consists of 3 nodes.

When I want to refer to HDFS , YARN etc (services installed using Ambari) do I have to use URI for individual nodes ? Or is there any unified URI that represents whole cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe providing some more context into what you are trying to use the URI for will help us better answer your question.

However, in general each service consists of one or more components. It's common for components to be installed on some nodes and not others, in which case a unified URI would not be useful. You would address a component by the node and port its running on if it has a running process (Master or Slave component).

For example the Yarn service has a few components, some of which are: Resource Manager, Node Manager, and client. The yarn client will be installed on 1 or more nodes (A cardinality of 1+). The Resource manager has a cardinality of 1. Node Manager has a cardinality of 1+.